# How to fix navigationlink producing blank screen? - SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I am having trouble with with Xcode not outputting the right text description of a guitar object when clicking a navigation link to display its description.  I am wondering if this is a glitch with Xcode or if there is something I need to change in order to display the right text.  I do not have an Apple Developer account so I can't test it out on my iOS device.

```
struct Guitar: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    let modelName: String
    let brandName: String
    let image: UIImage
    let imgPath: String
    let color: String
    let description: String
    
    init(modelName: String, brandName: String, imgPath: String, color: String, description: String) {
        self.modelName = modelName
        self.brandName = brandName
        self.imgPath = imgPath
        self.image = UIImage(named: self.imgPath)!
        self.color = color
        self.description = description
    }
}
```

```
class GuitarsContainer : ObservableObject {
    @Published var guitars = [Guitar]()
    
    init() {
        guitars.append(Guitar(modelName: "Ltd EC-256 Snow White", brandName: "ESP", imgPath: "esp_ltd_ec-256_snow_white", color: "White", description: ""))
        guitars.append(Guitar(modelName: "CR-6 Aquaburst", brandName: "Schecter", imgPath: "schecter_cr-6_aquaburst", color: "Green", description: ""))
        guitars.append(Guitar(modelName: "Stratocaster Limited Edition HSS Ebony", brandName: "Fender", imgPath: "fender_strat_limited_edition_hss_ebony", color: "Black", description: ""))
        guitars.append(Guitar(modelName: "RG550", brandName: "Ibanez", imgPath: "ibanez_rg550_yellow", color: "Yellow", description: ""))
        guitars.append(Guitar(modelName: "SG", brandName: "Gibson", imgPath: "gibson_sg", color: "Red", description: ""))
    }
}
```

```
struct GuitarDetailView: View {
    let guitar: Guitar
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(guitar.imgPath)
                .resizable()
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity , maxHeight: 450)
                .padding(.bottom)
            Text(guitar.modelName)
            Text(guitar.brandName)
            Spacer()
            NavigationLink(destination: DescriptionView(description: guitar.description)) {
                Text("See Description")
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .navigationTitle("Detailed Look")
    }
}

struct DescriptionView: View {
    var description: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(description)
    }
}

struct GuitarDetailView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        GuitarDetailView(guitar: Guitar(modelName: "Ltd EC-256 Snow White", brandName: "ESP", imgPath: "esp_ltd_ec-256_snow_white", color: "White", description: "Some of the most highly-regarded guitars in history have many similarities to the affordable and popular LTD EC-256FM. Mahogany body and 3 pc. neck? Check. Rosewood fingerboard and flamed maple top? Check and check. Covered passive pickups, set-neck construction, and 22XJ frets?You get it all, without the massive price tag you’d usually expect from such a well-made single-cutaway electric guitar. The EC-256FM is at home on blues, classic rock, hard rock, progressive rock, fusion, and much more, and it’s available in new see-thru Cobalt Blue and see-thru purple finishes."))
    }
```

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var guitarsContainer = GuitarsContainer()
    
    @State private var searchText = ""

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                List(guitarsContainer.guitars, id: \.id) { guitar in
                    HStack {
                        NavigationLink(destination: GuitarDetailView(guitar: guitar)) {
                            Image(guitar.imgPath)
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width: 200, height: 200, alignment: .center)
                        }
                    }
                    Text(guitar.brandName + " " + guitar.modelName)
                        .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                }
                .searchable(text: $searchText)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Guitar Shop")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
```

Comment: Well if you look at `GuitarsContainer`, you can see that you're adding an empty `String` as a description.

Comment: even after changing it to `var description: String` the problem still persists

Comment: No no that's not what I meant, look at where you're appending to your array.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you are not providing the description itself where you are populating the model.

```
class GuitarsContainer : ObservableObject {
@Published var guitars = [Guitar]()

init() {
    guitars.append(Guitar(modelName: "Ltd EC-256 Snow White", brandName: "ESP", imgPath: "esp_ltd_ec-256_snow_white", color: "White", description: "Your description goes here"))
    guitars.append(Guitar(modelName: "CR-6 Aquaburst", brandName: "Schecter", imgPath: "schecter_cr-6_aquaburst", color: "Green", description: "Your description goes here"))
    guitars.append(Guitar(modelName: "Stratocaster Limited Edition HSS Ebony", brandName: "Fender", imgPath: "fender_strat_limited_edition_hss_ebony", color: "Black", description: "Your description goes here"))
    guitars.append(Guitar(modelName: "RG550", brandName: "Ibanez", imgPath: "ibanez_rg550_yellow", color: "Yellow", description: "Your description goes here"))
    guitars.append(Guitar(modelName: "SG", brandName: "Gibson", imgPath: "gibson_sg", color: "Red", description: "Your description goes here"))
}
```

}

I have changed this part of code and added descriptions field as "Your description goes here", change it to what is required by you.